# Is std::list better than std::vector if one is storing pointers?

Tags: c++, stl

I generally avoid std::list, but in a case where I'm storing pointers, would it be more advantageous to use a std::list since I could then randomly insert pointers without having to move all my other pointers? What advantages and disadvantages would this present over a `std::vector<Some*>`

Thanks

Comment: The only way to really find out is to run performance tests. Also, you may be interested in [Boost.Pointer Container](http://boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html) if your containers own the pointers.

Comment: How many pointers would be there in container? Are they all inserted at once or during time? Are some pointers going to be removed from container?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since copy construction of a pointer is trivial, the decision here is not about whether one or the other is better for storing pointers but which is better for your needs.

If you really need to do lots of random inserts (and deletes?) then `list` could work better though it's not a simple decision - perhaps a `vector` with reserved space would be preferable, even then.  Do you want the per-node overhead of a `list` just to store a pointer?  On 32-bit Windows, that's 12 bytes per entry in the `list`, plus heap management overhead for a total of 20+ bytes per entry.  This does not help data locality over time either.  Meanwhile, `vector` uses four bytes per entry (again on 32-bit) and is guaranteed to store its elements in a contiguous block.

You have to deal with memory cleanup on `erase`/`clear`/destruction of the container either way, unless you wrap the pointer element as a smart pointer of some kind.  An alternative to ease memory management of your `Some*`s would be one of the [Boost pointer containers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html).

See also [here](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/054.htm) for some analysis of `list`, `vector` and `deque`.  Personally, I'm increasingly of the opinion that `list` is not that useful in the mainstream.

Comment: `list` is useful if ordering matters and you add/remove elements at random positions. Especially range of elements.

Comment: @Dialecticus: actually, `list` only really shines because it's a node based container, meaning that its iterators invalidation conditions are very sparse, quite unlike vector. That is, you can store an iterator to an element of the list, do any number of insertions/removals, as long as you didn't remove the element pointing to by the iterator you stored, it is still valid.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's ***especially pointers*** where using `std::vector` instead of `std::list` should be considered even with many insertions/removals at random positions. Pointers are very cheap to copy (in fact, I'd expect my standard library implementation to ***use CPU intrinsics*** to do this), so that the higher locality of `std::vector`'s data might by far outweigh the theoretically better fitness of `std::list` for random insertions/removals.

Anyway, you will have to measure your application (and *not* an artificial test case) to know for sure.

Comment: I think he's interested in `list<Some>` versus `vector<Some*>`

Comment: @Inverse: I'm not sure how to read this into "Is std::list better than std::vector if one is storing pointers?"

Comment: both `list<Some>` and `vector<Some*>` would avoid copy construction. That's what I figured the question was asking about, otherwise it's rather basic question for someone with 3k.

Answer (score 1):

In general, your first choice should be `vector` -- also, when you store pointers.

Compare the decision with this question in C (-ish): *When do I choose*

```
struct linked_items {
  element      *item;
  linked_items *next;
};
```

*over*

```
   element* items[];  /* array of pointers to items */
```

*?*

There are cases, but first check if you can apply the "easier" data structure, i.e. the `vector`.

Answer (score 0):

Generally when you need a container which stores something and then randomly deletes it then the best would be a `set`. To delete something you need to find it first, which is `O(n)` for vector and list and `O(log(n))` for set. If found then deleting it is instant for list but `O(n)` for vector, and again O(log(n)) for set.

So:

- consider `vector` if you very rarely
  search or delete from this
  container;
- consider `list` if you very rarely search in container;
- consider `set` otherwise.

A `vector` is the most memory and cache efficient. If you know number of elements then using `reserve()` you can make it 100% memory efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Based on bench marking studies, I prefer to use vector unless there are other strong use cases to support linked list (with some overhead info). But take care of the insertion and removal inefficiencies (on average) in a better way.

## Here goes my thoughts:

```
vector<SomeObject*> vecSomeObjectPointers;
vector<size_t> vecInvalidPointerIndices;// could be zero size, if no objects are removed
```

### Creating/adding new SomeObject element:

```
void AddNewObject()
{
    SomeObject* ptrSomeObject = new SomeObject;
    ptrSomeObject->PopulateSomeObject(); // add any extra memory if needed by SomeObject members
    ptrSomeObject->DoAnyOtherWorkOnSomeObjectBeforeStoring();

    size_t TotalInValidIndices = vecInvalidPointerIndices.size();
    if(TotalInValidIndices > 0) 
    {
    //re-use the invalid location/index of vector to hold new object
    vecSomeObjectPointers[vecInvalidPointerIndices[TotalInValidIndices-1]] = ptrSomeObject;
    vecInvalidPointerIndices.pop_back();
    }
    else vecSomeObjectPointers.push_back(ptrSomeObject); // new Object pointer at the end
}
```

### Deleting an existing SomeObject element:

```
void DeleteAnExistingObject()
{
    //Find the index of the object to be deleted based on certain input criteria. Ex: value stored etc..
    SomeObject* ptrSomeObject;
    for(auto& itr=vecSomeObjectPointers.begin(); itr != vecSomeObjectPointers.end(); ++itr)
    {
        ptrSomeObject = itr;
        if(ptrSomeObject->SomeObjectDeletionCriteriaSatisfied())
        {
            // make sure to delete any extra memory allocated to SomeObject members
            delete ptrSomeObject; // re-claim allocated memory

            // just invalidate the pointer info rather deleting it from vector to save re-shuffling time
            itr = NULL; 

            //Store the corresponding index to be used for holding a new object to be inserted next time
            vecInvalidPointerIndices.push_back(itr - vecSomeObjectPointers.begin());
        }
    }
}
```

### Working on existing SomeObject elements of the vector using Linear Search time:

```
void DoSomeWorkOnAnExistingObject()
{
    SomeObject* ptrSomeObject;
    for(auto& itr=vecSomeObjectPointers.begin(); itr != vecSomeObjectPointers.end(); ++itr)
    {
        if(itr == NULL) continue;
        //Do some work on object data to maintain it
        ptrSomeObject = itr;
    }
}
```

Any other thoughts are welcome...

Answer (score 0):

I assume you ask about [`std::list<Foo*>` would be really slow due to many indirections]

```
std::vector<Foo*> objects
```

Vs

```
std::list<Foo> objects
```

`std::vector`:

- Fast traversal
- Random access to different `Foo` objects
- `Foo` can be abstract
- You need to `delete`your objects manually
- Slow insertion if not at the end

`std::list`:

- No need to manually `delete` objects
- Fast insertion
- Slow traversal
- No random access to different `Foo` objects
- `Foo` cannot be abstract

EDIT:

I realised that there is one situation when std::vector does not work unless your objects are owned by someone else. Consider this recursive thing

```
class Foo
    {
    public:
        ~Foo(); /**<Now this must be recursive, otherwise it would need std::stack, which results in potential exception from dtor!*/
    private:
        std::vector<Foo*> m_children;
    };
```